# Python GDAL showing incorrect metadata for GRIB file

Tags: python, gdal, grib

I'm trying to read a GRIB file containing ERA-5 single level data that I downloaded from the Climate Data Store (CDS, https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=form).

Opening the grib-file in the NOAA Weather and Climate Toolkit shows me that all the correct data is inside the file, i.e., the variable names match the data that I selected in the CDS and I can also check the dates/times of the variables, they are correct. See this screenshot:

[image: variables inside my grib file.]

However, when I open the same file using python/GDAL, i see metadata that is completely different. I'm running the following little script to see which variables are inside the file:

```
import gdal
import numpy as np

filepath = r"F:\era5\sfc_2008_01.grib"

dataset = gdal.Open(filepath)

var_names_long = np.array([])

for layer in range(1, dataset.RasterCount):

    meta = dataset.GetRasterBand(layer).GetMetadata()

    var_names_long = np.append(var_names_long, meta['GRIB_COMMENT'])

print(np.unique(var_names_long))
```

This gives as output:

```
['Convective cloud cover [%]' 'Density [kg/m^3]'
 'Evaporation (of water) [m]' 'Ice cover (ice=1;no ice=0) [proportion]'
 'Precipitable water content [kg/m^2]' 'Salinity [kg/kg]'
 'Surface pressure [Pa]' 'Total cloud cover [%]'
 'Total column water [kg/m^2]' 'Total precipitation [m]'
 'Water runoff [kg/m^2]']
```

These are completely different variables, that I've never downloaded/selected?! Any ideas what might be causing this? It seems to me like it's a problem inside GDAL, since the NOAA toolkit gives the correct names... I'm using gdal 2.4.0 (which is the most recent version).

Comment: I didn't even know that GDAL could parse GRIB metadata! Very curious to see the reasons why it's showing bad metadata though. Could it be that those are empty dictionaries used as placeholders for when data is written to the file?

Comment: Im digging a bit now to figure out whats happening... What I've discovered is that for example the parameter "vertical integral of northward cloud frozen water flux" has a number 91.162 associated with it in the ECWMF system (see here https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5+data+documentation). That number 91 can also be found in this table (https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/on388/table2.html), which gives the description "Ice cover (ice=1, no ice=0)". Same goes for the numbers 71, 72, 88, 89 and 90. So it seems like somehow a lookup table is being mixed up...

Comment: Haven't found a solution (this seems to be a bug inside GDAL to me), but instead have switched to using cfgrib (found here https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib), which works nicely.